# Deleting and updating documents in Lucene index

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Am using `Lucene.Net.dll`, version 2.0.0.4.

Looks like its `IndexWriter` class does not have methods for `DeleteDocument` or `UpdateDocument`. Am i missing something here? How do I achieve delete, update functionality in this version of Lucene.Net?

Version 2.1 Lucene.dll seems to have support for delete and update documents:

```
public virtual void DeleteDocuments(Term term);
public virtual void UpdateDocument(Term term, Document doc);
```

In [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_1_0/) is the source code for verion 2.1, but I will have to download all the files one by one and then build a DLL out of it.

Can I download latest `Lucene.dll` and Highlighter from some site?

Answer (score 4):

I've documented how I update Lucene.NET Documents here: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20090516051530/http://www.ifdefined.com/blog/post/2009/02/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In older version of Lucene, deleting documents could only be done with an [IndexReader](https://www.google.com/search?q=lucene+indexreader). To update a document, simply delete the old version and add a new one.

I don't know about the dll download, sorry.

Comment: @John thanks... this question and answers are pretty old. I urge readers to look for answers elsewhere.

Comment: i have an open question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/11286712/335105 if you can help i'll be obliged ...