# Unable to delete the existing document in lucene index

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I am using Lucene.Net (version 2.9.4.1) to implement a simple search module. I'm trying to delete the document if it exists in the index using the following code,

```
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
var indexWriter = new IndexWriter(
    LuceneSearch._luceneDir,
    analyzer,
    IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);            

var searchQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("ListID", listingDoc.Get("ListID")));

indexWriter.DeleteDocuments(searchQuery);
```

where `listingDoc` is of type `Document` i'm trying to delete the document if it exists and then add it again to the index, the adding part works fine but the deleting part is not working that is the document is not deleted if it exists. Therefore if i search a term and it matches it is shown multiple times... Please point out what iam doing wrong here

I am using ASP.Net MVC3 and Entity Framework4. every time a record is updated i intend to update the index but instead its been duplicated. and when i search it i get the result twice or thrice depending upon the number of times i do the update.

I tried using `indexWriter.UpdateDocument(args);` to no avail...

Comment: do you commit your changes and refresh IndexSearchers after you delete the documents?

Comment: @JfBeaulac yup `indexWriter.Commit();`

Comment: Does UpdateDocument cause the same duplication behavior, or does it just not do anything?

Comment: @itsadok it causes the same behavior, first time if the index is not created it creates one but the next time when it should update the index it creates another (redundant)document...

Comment: the `ListID` is `stored` but not `indexed` should i index it too? its the primary key...

Comment: Yes. The field needs to be indexed if you want to retrieve documents by it, which is what a primary key is used for.

Comment: @itsadok tnx alot for your time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When debugging deletions it can sometimes be useful to perform a search with the same parameters as the delete command, to see exactly what is going to get deleted.

If you're doing a `deleteDocuments(query)` you should use an `IndexSearcher` like this:

```
IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(indexWriter.GetReader());
TopDocs topDocs = is.Search(query, 100);
```

And see what you get in the topDocs. I suspect you'll find that the query doesn't return any results.

Comment: that did it!!!!!!!! can you add the comment in which you stated that the `RSList` id should be indexed too ...

Comment: and tnx for the guidance `:)`

Comment: This helped find my issue, I had not set my `Id` field to be indexed. After I changed the field to be `Field.Index.ANALYZED_NO_NORMS` it was able to find the document to delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply:

```
    Query query = queryParser.parse("My Query!");
    writer.deleteDocuments(query);
```